# MovieClip property - what is the url it goes when I click on it

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-2

I have bought a flash template in an online store. There are different buttons on it and some of them link to existing local html files from the pack - index-1.html, index-2.html etc. There are also some buttons that don't go anywhere right now but they are intended to be linked to some urls too. They react with animation on mouse rollover and I suppose they should go to some url if I set it somewhere on click. But there is no documentation about that in the pack. I searched through the Flash source file and all html pages files for something like "index", "geturl", also looked through them manually to realize how it could be made but with no luck. So, my question - is that possible that way or another to make that MovieClip button link to some my page, for example, "contacts.html".
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Select the Button , press F9 , and then Write the following code:

```
on(Press)
{
getURL(Your URL here);
}
```

Or By selecting the Look out for the Instance Name.If able to get the Instance name, Select the 1st Frame. Press F9 and then Write:

```
isntanceName.onPress=function()
{
getURL(Your URL here);
}
```

Flash is Case Sensitive. So be carefull. Not able to test my code as Donot have flash right now.